# finding right regex pattern in java

Tags: java

So lets say I have array of Strings of following type

```
something **foo**garblesomething somethingelse
something **foobar**blahblah somethingelse
and so on
```

So essentially data are triples

Now, in the middle part of string

Notice key word "foo" and "foobar"

What I want to do is:

```
if "foo" in string:
    return 1
else if "foobar" in string:
    return 2
else -1
```

How do I do this in java?
Thanks

Comment: A less contrived example might help - for example to solve this exact problem you could just search for "foobar" first, and if it isn't found, search for "foo".

Comment: The specific method to use would be contains(). There's no reason to use a regex.

Comment: [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: There is **absolutely no need for a regex** in this situation.  Opting to use a regex will do nothing but make your code less efficient and more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `String#contains(String)`

```
if (str.contains("foobar"))
    return 2;
else if (str.contains("foo"))
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

Important to check for `foobar` before `foo` otherwise it will return 1 for both cases.